# Generating a list of lengths in one line of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate, one-liner

Quick question... Sort of random.

I would like to find a way to return a list containing all the lengths of the items in a separate list in **one line** of python... Using python 3.8 ... I tried the below:

The list that needs to be worked on (yes, each index must be contained in it's own list, I know this is not ordinary or practical...):
`tmp =[['one'], ['two'], ['three']]`

The code I tried:

```
lens = [len(item[a][0]) for a, item in enumerate(tmp)]
```

Error it returned:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

...

Granted, usually a statement like:
`lens = [len(item) for item in tmp]` would suffice here, and that works perfectly fine if we have a list **not** containing sub-lists... But, I'd love it if I could grab the string-length of each sub-index all in one line.

For the person who I imagine will ask: No, I dont **have** to do this in one line, but got into a cheeky little debate with another programmer friend about the fastest way to do this, and I want to know if it's possible in just a single line.  Not practical, I know.

It makes sense to me that, at calltime, python does not yet have value for `a` or `item` (explaining my index out of range error) because I am hoping to assign value to them via `enumerate(tmp)` ...
Typing the same code out line by line works, naturally, since enumerate can make the assignments to `a` and `item` once it's been called...

But I don't exactly see why something like `lens = [len(item) for item in tmp]` will work, but this wont. The variable assignments would seem to occur in the same order, no?
I've experienced before that Python is not very good at handling functions that return multiple values/objects... Perhaps it'll be an update in 3.9? Who knows!

Cheers! (:

Comment: `lens = [len(item[0]) for item in tmp]`?

Comment: When you do `for a, item in enumerate(tmp)`, what are you expecting the value of `a` to be the first time? What are you expecting the value of `item` to be the first time? What are you expecting `item[a][0]` to evaluate to?

Comment: For the input `tmp =[['one'], ['two'], ['three']]`, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: Almost, but that would only return the length of the first index, and it would also return a value of 1 since that index points to a list which has a length of 1 item... That's why I had item[a][0] ... Each sub-list will contain only one item, so the 0 index is a safe constant, but the primary index needs to iterate.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The output should be: [3, 3, 4] (the length of each string contained in each sub-index)

Comment: Okay, but why is your input `[['one'], ['two'], ['three']]`, and not simply `['one', 'two', 'three']`?

Comment: Does https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ help?

Comment: Ah, that resource may have helped... There may be a way to do it with a nested loop. 
However, to answer your previous questions, I expect that when that list is called into creation, it will, in a loop iterated by enumerate(tmp), cause item to be the index in tmp corresponding to a (the iterator) meaning that item[a][0] would contain the string 'one' since enumerate() had assigned a a value of 0 (on first cycle) and item a value of ['one'], and so on and so forth.  I realize that having the list of lists is a pain, the point of that was to make this challenge harder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the answer:

```
lens = [len(tmp[a][0]) for a, item in enumerate(tmp)]
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
lens = [len(item[0]) for a, item in enumerate(tmp)]
```

In your code, a is the index while item is each individual list item.

Comment: I haven't tested this but I believe you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Karl Knechtel's answer pointing me to a python-lists basics solved this.

We can use a nested loop:

```
lens = [len(row) for item in tmp for row in item]
```